# Prove whether $2^n = O(n^4 + n^2)$ is true

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have been given a set of questions on BigO for my university course, however I'm really struggling to wrap my head around it, and was wondering if anyone would be able to explain this example please?

The question is:

Decide whether $2^n = O(n^4 + n^2)$ is true, and justify your answer.

We've been given the following information to help us solve the problems, but after following her examples, I'm still struggling to apply it to the tasks. I'd really appreciate any help anyone may be able to give, thanks!

| Counting Basic Operations | Time Complexity (bigO) | Name (time) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | O(1) | constant |
| n + 3 | O(n) | linear |
| $n^4 + 3n + 1$ | O($n^4$) | polynomial |
| $log(n) + 1$ | O($log(n)$) | logarithmic |
| $log(n) + n^2$ | O($n^2$) | polynomial (quadratic) |
| $nlog(n)$ | O($nlog(n)$) | quasilinear |
| $n^4 + 4^n$ | O($2^n$) | exponential |
| $n! + 2^n$ | O($n!$) | factorial |

[image: 1. For any f, f = O(f)]

Comment: Just use the definition of $O(f)$. Can for any $N $ big enough be $2^n\leq M n^4$ for every $n>N$?

Comment: @dmtri Thank you for your reply. So if I were to substitute a value such as 64 into it, where it becomes $2^{64}$ > $64^4 + 64^2$, that would consitute a valid reasoning? Would I need to make reference to the constant $c$?

Comment: You are welcome! Not just a value... You need to show that if $M>0$ then there is always a $N>0$ so that for every $n>N$ it is $2^n>Mn^4$

Comment: $n^4 + 4^n = O(2^n)$ doesn't look right.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Limit Comparison test. Take $f(n) = 2^{n}, g(n) = n^{4} + n^{2}$. Now compute:
$$L := \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n}}{n^{4} + n^{2}}$$.

We have the following:

- If $L = 0$, then $2^{n} \in o(n^{4} + n^{2})$. In particular, $2^{n} \in O(n^{4} + n^{2})$, and $2^{n} \not \in \Omega(n^{4} + n^{2})$.
- If $0 < L < \infty$, then $2^{n} \in \Theta(n^{4} + n^{2})$.
- If $L = \infty$, then $2^{n} \in \omega(n^{4} + n^{2})$. In particular, $2^{n} \in \Omega(n^{4} + n^{2})$ and $2^{n} \not \in O(n^{4} + n^{2})$.

Comment: Answer good for advanced students.  But unfortunately, notations like $\in$ and $\Omega$ are probably beyond what the OP has learned in his course.

Comment: +1, I liked the answer because you use $g\in O(f)$ and not $g= O(f)$, which I personally dislike....

Answer (score 0):

In case you may know that the sequnece $\frac{2^n}{n^4}$ is not bounded then there is a simple trick to determine by contradiction: Suppose that $2^n=O(n^4+n^2)$ then there is $M>0$ and $N>0$ such that for every $n>N$, it is $2^n\leq M(n^4+n^2)\leq M(2n^4)\implies \frac{2^n}{n^4}\leq2M$ , which implies that  $\frac{2^n}{n^4}$ is bounded, absurd.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\displaylines {2^n> {n \choose 5}={n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)\over 5!}\ge {n(n-4)^4\over 120}\\
={n(2n-8)^4\over 16\cdot 120}\ge {n^5\over 16\cdot 120},\qquad n\ge 8}$$
Hence $${2^n\over n^4+n^2}\ge {2^n\over 2n^4}\ge {n\over  32\cdot 120}, \qquad n\ge 8$$